# Struggling to reproduce terminal from The Unix Programming Environment (1983)

Tags: linux, unix, terminal

I have been reading *The Unix Programming Environment* & performing the included exercises. I understand that this work is somewhat dated, but I have found it to be an excellent resource.

In the first chapter, there are a few exercises in which the reader is presented with an interaction with the terminal & is asked to explain the interaction. Here is an example:

> **Exercise 1-1**. Explain what happens with
>
> ```
> $ date\@
> ```

In the text, it is explained that an `@` is to be interpreted as the *line kill character*. The equivalent on my system is `^u`, but I can emulate the terminal in the book with `stty kill @`.

Based on the reading & my intuition, I would expect the invocation of `date\@` to return something to the effect of:

```
date@: command not found
```

The text supports this reasoning:

> If you precede either `#` or `@` by a backslash `\`, it loses its special meaning. So to enter a # or @, type `\#` or `\@`.

My problem is that I cannot even type the example into my terminal. As soon as I type `@`, the line is erased. The backslash does not appear to escape the line kill character.

Assuming I am correct about how the escape character should interact with terminal control characters, how can I set up my system (Ubuntu GNU/Linux) to emulate the behavior from the text?

Here is another similar exercise:

> **Exercise 1-2.** Most shells (though not the 7th edition shell) interpret `#` as introducing a comment, and ignore all text from the `#` to the end of the line. Given this, explain the following transcript, assuming your erase character is also `#`:

```
$ date
Mon Sep 26 12:39:56 EDT 1983
$ #date
Mon Sep 26 12:40:21 EDT 1983
$ \#date
$ \\#date
#date: not found
$
```

With my erase character set to `#`, it is impossible to replicate this transcript. The backslash does not appear to escape the erase character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Terminal gets and responds to your keystrokes before the Shell does. So the shell has no chance to escape the @ since the terminal deletes the whole line first.

When you typed

```
stty kill @
```

you told the shell to tell the terminal to kill the line every time you press @

Type

```
stty kill ^u
```

and your shell will start to behave the way you expect and ^u will kill lines for you.

^v is the escape char for the terminal
\ is the escape char for the shell.

Comment: I'm afraid this does not answer my question. I understand how to restore the original behavior of my terminal. I would like to know why escaping the _line kill_ character with a backslash does not appear to have any effect.

Comment: because the terminal reads the line kill character first. Leaving no line for the shell to read. You talk to the terminal, the terminal talks to the shell. If you tell the terminal to kill a line, it wont send the line to the shell.

Comment: The text suggests that there is another mechanism inside the kernel that interprets the backslash: _"When an erase or line kill character is preceded by a backslash, the kernel discards the backslash and holds the following character without interpretation"_. Is this no longer the case? Is there any way to emulate this behavior?

Comment: The behaviour you described is the way all shells work. Yours is not different. The point you seem to be missing is that the terminal is not the shell. They are two different things.

Comment: I do understand this point. Please see the clarifying example I added.

Comment: That is the correct and expected behavior. Re-binding terminal erase and kill-line characters is the kind of prank we would pull in college in the '80s. Don't do it.

Comment: But can you replicate the transcript for Exercise 1-2 on your machine? Once I get to `$ \#date`, the behavior of my machine diverges from the text. The `#` erases the backslash and date is invoked normally. The transcript shows the `#` escaped by the backslash **before** being passed to the shell, which interprets `#` as a comment.

Comment: if for example you bound the # key to terminal erase and you then wanted to type a # to the shell rather than erase a char, then you need to tell the terminal to not act on the next char by pressing ^v. now when you press # it will arrive at the shell.

Comment: Thank you, this does work for me. If you could put this point in your answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

This is an antique question, about an even more antique book, but I'd like to set the record straight here because the currently accepted answer did not answer your question.

Believe it or not, when I learned UNIX from this book in 1985 (!), this part of the book was already antiquated, and the stuff about "#", "@" and "\" already did not work, and I remember being puzzled exactly like you on why it doesn't work, and whether I was doing something wrong. But it wasn't wrong per se - just out of date. Let me explain how in a previous era (perhaps a decade before the book was published?) this stuff was correct:

Before the advent of CRT terminals, there were "teletype" terminals - basically typewriters which print the characters you type (and the remote responses) on paper. On such teletypes, there was no "backspace". You couldn't erase something already typed. So the convention was that you typed a "#", and it erased, logically, the previous character. You'd still see both of them on the paper, but had to imagine both were deleted from the computer's input. So if you see on paper

```
helk#lo world
```

The computer actually received "hello world", with the "#" deleting the "k" behind it.
UNIX also allowed you to type one character, "@", to delete the *entire* line you just typed, if you made a lot of mistakes. So

```
oops I wrote a lot of crap I need to erase@hello world
```

Was again interpreted as just "hello world".

Finally, since sometimes you wanted to type an actual "#" or "@" characters and have them be taken literally, not as character-erase or line-erase commands, you also had an "escape character", which in very early days was "\". Note that this escape character was interpreted not by the shell, but rather by the Unix kernel's terminal driver, which communicated with the teletype.

When new CRT terminals appeared, these conventions were quickly phased out and became the ones we know today: The default erase character was no longer "#" but rather the backspace or delete key, and it really erases the character on the screen. The line-erase (somewhat confusingly known as "kill") became control-X or control-U. The escape character became control-V. You can also change these characters with the "stty" command, setting the "erase", "kill", or "lnext" attributes, but people rarely do. "stty -a" shows you all the current settings of these special characters (and many more).

Comment: Anyway, to "reproduce" the ancient terminal feeling on a modern machine, do: stty erase '#'; stty kill '@'; stty lnext '\'. Then run something which doesn't work in raw mode - e.g., "cat", and see the old behavior coming to life :-) Note that on the modern terminal the # and @ characters will actually erase what came before - this didn't happen on a teletype, and you had to imagine it happening :-)